# Why does PHP give unexpected output?

Tags: c#, php, conditional-statements

```
$i = 2;
$result = ($i == 2) ? "Two" : ($i == 1) ? "One" : "Other";

echo $result; // outputs: One
```

While the same code in C# outputs: Two

```
int i=2;
String result = (i == 2) ? "Two" : (i == 1) ? "One" : "Other" ;
Console.Write( result ); // outputs: Two
```

Comment: It's not unexpected, it's simply non-intuitive.... which is precisely why the docs recommend against nesting ternaries: `Note: 

It is recommended that you avoid "stacking" ternary expressions. PHP's behaviour when using more than one ternary operator within a single statement is non-obvious`

Comment: You have no heart for your compiler. Stacking ternaries...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ternary operators are evaluated **LEFT-TO-RIGHT**.

```
($i == 2) ? "Two" : ($i == 1) ? "One" : "Other"
"Two" ? "One" : "Other"  // first part evaluated to "Two"
"One"                    // non-empty strings evaluate to true
```

So you should get `One` in your output, not `Other`. It's a little tricky.

Wise words from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

> It is recommended that you avoid "stacking" ternary expressions. PHP's behaviour when using more than one ternary operator within a single statement is non-obvious.

Answer (score 2):

The explanation has already been provided by @light, but to get the result that you want you need additional braces:

```
$i = 3;
$result = ($i == 2) ? "Two" : (($i == 1) ? "One" : "Other");
echo $result, PHP_EOL;

$i = 2;
$result = ($i == 2) ? "Two" : (($i == 1) ? "One" : "Other");
echo $result, PHP_EOL;

$i = 1;
$result = ($i == 2) ? "Two" : (($i == 1) ? "One" : "Other");
echo $result, PHP_EOL;
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/609o9)

Answer (score 0):

It's because C# is strongly typed and requires a boolean value to be the first argument of ternary operator, while PHP is loosely typed and basically every value can be converted to it's boolean equivalent. Also, ternary operators are evaluated from left to right. What does it mean?

In C# we need boolean on the very left side of the operator, so this expression:

```
String result = (i == 2) ? "Two" : (i == 1) ? "One" : "Other" ;
```

will be evaluated in this order:

```
String result = (i == 2) ? "Two" : ((i == 1) ? "One" : "Other");
```

`i==2` is equal to `true` so `"Two"` will be assigned as a final result. In PHP it looks a bit different. We can interpret this expression:

```
$result = ($i == 2) ? "Two" : ($i == 1) ? "One" : "Other";
```

like this

```
$result = (($i == 2) ? "Two" : ($i == 1)) ? "One" : "Other";
```

`$i` is equal to 2, so value `"Two"` will be the result of the first expression. Non-empty string values are in PHP equal to true, so "One" will be the final result.